# What are the benefits of using :before and :after with font icons?

Tags: css, unicode, icons, font-face, pseudo-element

I've recently been reading a lot about font icons, and just about every site I see uses the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements in combination with the `content` property to insert font icons into the DOM.

However, I don't see the advantage of using these pseudo-elements for font icons. In fact, I feel like there are two big disadvantages to using them: `:before` and `:after` are not supported in IE7 and below, and it can be hard to position content using them.

As such, my question is this: Why use `:before` and `:after` at all to insert font icons into the DOM? I was thinking that maybe it has something to do with screen readers, but nowadays, all font icons services (like IcoMoon) seem to allocate the font icons to code points in the Unicode PUAs (Private Use Areas), which (from what I hear), are not read aloud by screen readers anyway.

To me, it seems much easier and more cross-browser compliant to simply add the font icons to the markup using HTML entities like `&#xE000;`.

To rephrase the question: What are the specific reasons why most people use `:before` and `:after` for font icons? Thank you very much.

Comment: “I'm curious what you all think” makes the question rather opinion-based. There are technical considerations that may be relevant, but the question is too vague (no specific technology is specified and cited).

Comment: I modified the question as per your suggestion, Jukka.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pretty theoretical difference.

The idea is that generated content is not considered part of the document, and has no semantic value. It should be ignored by agents that work on the page content, such as search engines and audio page readers (what real screen readers actually do is not necessarily always so clean, but that's another story).

This makes it a good fit for times when you want to add visual decoration with no semantic content, which is the proper use for icon fonts. This is no different from using a background image to highlight an item, or an image with `alt=""`.

If you simply wrote `&#xE000;` in a page then that does theoretically have semantic content... just not any well-defined semantic content, it's “weird unknown character”. Although it shouldn't mean anything, it may do for specific communities (U+E000 might be considered a rune, or a picture of Tux) and it may be treated inappropriately by some tools because of that.

(Where this all falls down is that people *do* use icon fonts as more than decoration, to signify meaningful differentiation that is not imparted by the document content. And since FontAwesome's own examples page contains this inaccessible kind of misuse, it's hardly surprising that people do that. Web designers are visual animals, you can lead them to semantics-appropriate tools, but you can't make them think semantically.)

Comment: Very good answer, bobince. Thanks a lot. I think you hit the nail on the head that font icons are not designed to be semantic, but people use them as such. I asked this question because I'm designing a site where the client wants to heavily use font icons, and in many cases, the icons are all you have as the "content" for links, etc. As such, I am thinking that just writing the icons out using HTML entities would be best (not to mention, the most cross-browser friendly solution). You are right too though that U+E000 (for example) is a very arbitrary code point that could have many meanings.